# Problem Uploading File Using FTPS Protocol

Tags: java, file-upload, ftps

I'm try to upload file using FTPS.

Currently I use the library `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;`

This is part of code that I use:

`FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("SSL", true); ftpClient.connect(host, port); ftpClient.login(user, password);`  
And I check the connection using:
`ftpClient.isConnected()`

This return a boolean value, when is ok return: true

The problem is when try to upload a file, for this I Use:

`ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fis);`

This return false and the message: `501 Server cannot accept argument.`

I am grateful for any support that the community can give me with this issue.

Thanks

**This is the Code snippet that I use:**

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("SSL",true);`
try {
  FTPClientConfig  conf=newFTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_NT);  
  ftpClient.configure(conf); 
  ftpClient.connect(host,port); 
  ftpClient.login(user, pass); 
  System.out.println("Connected?: "+ftpClient.isConnected());
  ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
  String path = carpetaLocal;
  File directorio = new File(path);
  File[] ficheros = directorio.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
  File file = (ficheros[i]);
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  Client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
  ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
  boolean res = ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), fis);
  System.out.println("File Upload Successful?: " + res);
 }
 ftpClient.disconnect();
 System.out.println("Connected?: " +ftpClient.isConnected());     
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }
```

Comment: 501 is [Syntax error in parameters or arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

Comment: mmm ok, but when I try upload file, using a outputStream, creates the empty file, but does not allow to write it. After the response is java.net.SocketException: "Broken pipe (Write failed)". The file that I try upload Is a zip.

Comment: First try uploading a zip with a different command line client from the same box

Comment: I don't understand your idea, I'll tell you what I tried: I tried the transfer with FileZilla and it worked. I managed with the same code to create a new file (e.g. text) on the server and overwrite it without problems. So I don't understand why the process from my java application s not successful when I transfer the zip file.

Comment: Probably need to see the full `storeFile` code

Comment: Happy New Year, I updated the post with a code snippet, please check.

Comment: *This return false and the message: 501 Server cannot accept argument.* Please post the full error as text, formatted as code. I don't know where that is coming from as "cannot accept" is not a string that appears in the Commons Net source

Comment: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
    USER *******
    331 Password required
    PASS *******
    230 User logged in.
    CWD /
    250 CWD command successful.
    TYPE I
    200 Type set to I.
    PORT 192,168,31,210,216,149
    501 Server cannot accept argument.

Comment: Formatted as code in the question please